# How to handle special characters in solr?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

Do we have any solr configuration in solr or do we need to append Back slashes in the code level in q parameter before we pass to solr.

Please let me know how we can handle special characters.

At my current configuration I just kept the word delimiter filter factory enabled at query time analyzer in text_general by toggling preserveOriginal set to 1 and catenateWords set to 1, but we don't get accurate relevant results.

Eg: When searching for 37/eNOS(S633), getting no results.
Expected results: To get the list of products.
Actual results:  No results found.

To get the results made the changes at query end and enabled word delimeter filter and toggled CatenateWords=1 and preserveOrginal=1.
In analysis, it preserves original and since we have catenateWords we get enoss633.

But for other exact search we get irrelevant results because of catenatewords=1.

So do we have any other configuration to handle special character or do we need to append with "back slash" at the code level ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you share your actual test text and the field type applied to the field in the question . it would help. Please mention actual result and expected result as well. Do analyaze the text analysis on the solr admin page. It would help you more

Comment: `/` is one of the special characters that should be escaped. If you're not using a library (which should do this automagically for you), you'll want to look at the special characters that need to be escaped when sending a query directly to Solr: `+ - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ /`: https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_4_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Escaping_Special_Characters

Comment: Which library we have to handle the special character ? @MatsLindh

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti, have updated it, could you please suggest me now ?

Comment: That would depend on how you're querying Solr - are you already using a library or not? Which language are you using? Java has SolrJ, PHP has Solarium, Python has pysolr, etc.